# removing parent and children in flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to remove the parent and children of movieClip in my flash file using AS3.

The problem that I have is that i can only remove the child and the parent stays on the stage at all time!

this is my code to remove the parent and child:

```
    removeChild(clip_mc);
    clip_mc = null;
    gotoAndStop(2);
```

and this is how i create the movieclip and its children:

```
                     var clip_mc = new MovieClip();
                     // Add the rectangle graphic
                     clip_mc.addChild(rect);
                     // Add the text field
                     clip_mc.addChild(myText);

                     clip_mc.addChild(pictLdr2);
                     // Put the new movieClip on stage now
                     addChild(clip_mc);
                     // Make the mouse button mode true for the movieclip so user knows it is a button
                     clip_mc.buttonMode = true;
```

i thought, adding `removeChild();` would remove the parent as well but in my case it will only removes the child and the parent stays on the stage

could someone please advise on this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the parent in your case?  The code isn't clear on that.

Comment: If you have code on different frames, you should put all your code on one frame, the first frame.

Answer (score 1):

To remove an object, `clip_mc` in your case, you can do like this : ( comments into the code )

```
if(contains(clip_mc)){

    clip_mc.parent.removeChild(clip_mc) // removes clip_mc from it's container 

    trace(contains(clip_mc))            // gives : false

    trace(clip_mc)                      // gives : [object MovieClip]

    clip_mc = null                      // removes the reference of clip_mc

    trace(clip_mc)                      // gives : null

}
```

Code for test :

```
var rect:clp = new clp()

var clip_mc = new MovieClip()
    clip_mc.addChild(rect)
    clip_mc.buttonMode = true

addChild(clip_mc)

// of course, we activate this portion just at the end to remove clip_mc
if (contains(clip_mc)){
    clip_mc.parent.removeChild(clip_mc)
    clip_mc = null
}
```

Comment: that still leaves the actual parent clip_mc on the stage!

Comment: how do you verify if clip_mc is always on the stage ?

Comment: because i can see it on the stage!

Comment: I used your code and It works for me. I'll edit my answer to show you the exact code.

Comment: sorry but what is var rect:clp = new clp(); ? i get an error uaing your code which is: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: clp.

Comment: clp is movie clip in my library, I created just an instance of it for the test and I added it to clip_mc, for you, you should use your rect object as your first code.

Comment: I'm sorry but your code doesn't work either!! strange that you say it works for you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64521/discussion-between-user3806613-and-akmozo).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `clip_mc.parent.parent.removeChild(clip_mc.parent)`